# In React how to update page after deleting an item from favourite

Tags: reactjs, pagination, refresh

I'm facing a problem I don't know how to resolve.
I created a favourite tab containing all the characters the user saved.
In the favourite page it displays the tab.
The user can remove an item from his favourite by clicking on the top icon heart.
It works perfectly, the item is instantly removed but if I'm on the second page, and remove all the items from the page, I get a blank screen even if the pagination updates accordly (from 2 pages to 1).
I have to refresh manually the page so that it show the remaining items.
How can I force to refresh the page automatically ?
You can see on the image that when the item is deleted, the page 2 is deleted but I'm still on the deleted page (the 1 on pagination is not bold).
[image: screen]

Comment: Is the pagination number state stored in the URL? If you store it in the URL state, you could push onto the history using `react-router` after the deletion, such that it changes the state accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by "stored in the URL" ? Like a params ? The pagination is juste in a simple state. But I guess I could put it onto an URL params.

Comment: If it is in the state, then upon refreshing the page would go back to normal. I recommend putting the state in the URL, and reading from it and updating the URL state upon data deletion.

Comment: I put it in a state because I'm using react-paginate and until now I didn't have to put in on the URL. I'm gonna try your suggestion and let you know how it works.